# Spring 3 MVC -- HTTP 500 error, NoClassDefFoundException

Tags: spring-mvc, noclassdeffounderror

I am getting an HTTP 500 error when I start my Spring 3.2 MVC application with the following error in my console.  I am using Tomcat 7.0.29.

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [ghs1986] in context with path [/ghs1986] threw exception [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tomcat/util/scan/JarFactory] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFactory
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1676)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache.tldScanJar(TldLocationsCache.java:413)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache.access$100(TldLocationsCache.java:78)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache$TldJarScannerCallback.scan(TldLocationsCache.java:240)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.process(StandardJarScanner.java:234)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:159)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache.init(TldLocationsCache.java:224)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache.getLocation(TldLocationsCache.java:184)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.getTldLocation(JspCompilationContext.java:607)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:409)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:475)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1427)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:138)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:242)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:102)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:198)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:373)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:684)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:471)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:329)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1265)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1016)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:965)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:859)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:781)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I do have this mapping in ghs1986-servlet.xml

```
<mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="home" />
```

I also have this mapping in my controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/", "home"})
public String home() {
    return "home";
}
```

Comment: I dont think that will possible a Spring error. It seems like some trouble on Tomcat. Did you check your classpath for double jars ou missing jars? Take a look on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446050/noclassdeffounderror-in-websphere-jars-are-present

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem resolved by adding tomcat-util.jar to both my classpath and WEB-INF/lib.  tomcat-util.jar contains org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFactory.